# Converting ArcSDE to CAD using FME when blockreference involved?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form, cad

I try to convert some lines from ArcSDE to cad by FME and I have set `autocad_original_entity_type=autocad_lwpolyline` and `autocad_entity=autocad_line`, I suppose they will be line but they have been blockreference. I find `fme_geometry` is `fme_aggregate` and `fme_type` is `fme_line` in FMEINSPECTOR, it is strange.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that these lines are actually composed of multiple line features (called an Aggregate in FME terminology, that the CAD format you're writing to doesn't support aggregates, and so FME writes them as a block so that the relationship is preserved.

If you do want them as lines, and don't care about the relationship so much, insert a Deaggreator transformer. That will break the features down into individual lines.

***NB:*** Setting autocad_original_entity_type will do nothing on the Writer, since this is an attribute defined by the AutoCAD **Reader**. Setting autocad_entity might have an effect, but since the geometry itself doesn't match what you're telling the Writer, I guess FME will be automatically correcting this to match the geometry.